# Android Back-Button quits Phonegap-app when in textarea

Tags: android, cordova

In my Phonegap-app I handle Android's Back-button with `document.addEventListener("backbutton", mysuperawesomecallback, false)` This works fine so far. However, when I'm writing in a textfield the first click on the Back-Button hides the Keyboard and the second quits the app. When I take the focus of the textfield it works normal again.

How can I prevent to quit the app when I'm in a textfield?

Comment: The normal behaviour is to hide the input method with the first backbutton click and to go to the previous activity (or exit if it's the main). Can you please clarify your problem?

Comment: I've overwritten the behaviour of the Back-Button with the mentioned method. When I'm done writing in a textfield, I want to hook up the Back-Button to this method again. But instead my app quits.

What I want: Textfield writing -> hide Keyboard -> my back-button listener

What is happening: Textfield writing -> hide Keyboard -> app quits

Answer (score 4):

Add following lines into your main activity which is derived from DroidGap

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are actually running into a bug in PhoneGap. We've fixed this issue in PhoneGap 2.2.0 which will be out very soon.