# android phonegap back button crashes application

Tags: android, cordova

In phone gap project using android when i am pressing back button it stopes (froce close ) my app

with this logcat result

```
08-22 05:35:12.106: W/dalvikvm(1154): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6280288)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onKeyDown(CordovaActivity.java:1084)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2609)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2361)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1819)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3545)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2795)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-22 05:35:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my activity class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/firstfile.html");
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    //  wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/firstfile.html");
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/test.html");

        MyWebViewClient wvc = new MyWebViewClient();
        wv.setWebViewClient(wvc);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        ProgressDialog prDialog;

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            prDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null,
                    "loading, please wait...");
            prDialog.setCancelable(true);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            prDialog.dismiss();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

I have added

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
```

in my manifest file

Does anyone idea about this?

Comment: you need to handle/override the backbutton event default behaviour. Have a look over [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton) for backbutton event handling

Comment: i have done 1 silly mistake of public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
 insted of  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Answer (score 1):

you need to handle/override the backbutton event default behaviour. Have a look over [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton) for backbutton event handling

Answer (score 1):

Add following lines into your main activity which is derived from DroidGap

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

[Android Back-Button quits Phonegap-app when in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051508/android-back-button-quits-phonegap-app-when-in-textarea/13833557#13833557)